# $a^2+b^2=2Rc$,where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle.Then prove that $ABC$ is a right triangle

Tags: trigonometry

If in a triangle $ABC$,$c$ is the longest side and $a^2+b^2=2Rc$,where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle.Then prove that $ABC$ is a right triangle.

$a^2+b^2=2Rc\Rightarrow a^2+b^2=\frac{c^2}{\sin C}$
$\sin C=\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}$,how to proceed ahead?I am stuck.

Comment: Does the question exclude the use of web resources such as Wolfram Alpha (e.g. is it a contest question)? Are you familiar with multivariable calculus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In a $\triangle ABC$,  $c$ is the longest side  and $a^2+b^2=2Rc$,
>   where $R$ is the circumradius of the triangle. Prove that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle.

We have 
\begin{align}
\sin C&=\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2},
\\
\cos C&=
\tfrac12 \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{ab},
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
1&=\left(\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2
+\left(\tfrac12 \frac{-c^2+a^2+b^2}{ab}\right)^2
\end{align}
$\Rightarrow$
\begin{align}
0&=
\frac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)
((6 a^2 b^2+a^4+b^4) c^2+b^4 a^2+b^2 a^4-a^6-b^6)
}{
4 a^2 b^2 (a^2+b^2)^2
}
\end{align}

So one solution for $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$
certainly corresponds to a right triangle, $c^2=a^2+b^2$.
Assuming $a>b$, the other one is

\begin{align}
c^2&=
\frac{
(a^2+b^2)(a^2-b^2)^2
}{
(a^2+b^2)^2+4 a^2 b^2
}
\end{align}
or,
\begin{align}
c^2&=a^2
\frac{
\left(1-\tfrac{b^2}{a^2}\right)^2
}{
1+4\tfrac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}+\tfrac{b^2}{a^2}
}
<a^2,
\end{align}
hence for this solution $c$ is not the longest side,
the answer is: it is indeed a right triangle.

***Edit***

Example solution with "wrong" (that is, not right at all) triangle 
for which $a^2+b^2=2Rc$ ($c<a$):

[image]

\begin{align}
a&=2,\ b=1,\ c=\tfrac3{41}\sqrt{205}\approx 1.047645443
\\
\rho&=\tfrac12(a+b+c)=\tfrac32+\tfrac3{82}\sqrt{205}
\\
S&=\sqrt{\rho(\rho-a)(\rho-b)(\rho-c)}=\tfrac9{41}
\\
R&=\frac{abc}{4S}=\tfrac16\sqrt{205}
\end{align}
Check:
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2&=5
\\
2Rc&=2\cdot \tfrac16\sqrt{205}\cdot \tfrac3{41}\sqrt{205}=5.
\end{align}

Comment: +1 - That's a very "wrong" triangle indeed - in fact, to claim this satisfies the requirements would be really "obtuse".

Comment: @Marconius: Thanks. Yes, they all are obtuse, also 
one type among them is an isosceles one.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use the sine law.

$$\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = 2R \tag{1}$$

If you apply the sine law to sides $a,b$ the main equation becomes:

$$\begin{align}
&4R^2 \sin^2A + 4R^2 \sin^2B = 4R^2 \sin C \implies \\
&\sin^2A + \sin^2B = \sin C\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

For a triangle $C = 180^\circ - (A+B)$, so then

$$\sin C = \sin(A+B)$$

Substituting this into (2), we get:

$$\sin^2A + \sin^2B = \sin (A+B) \tag{3}$$

Can you show that a solution is $A+B=90^\circ$, so that $C=90^\circ$?

Comment: There is an obvious continuation from: $\sin^2A + \sin^2B = \sin (A+B) $?

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to show that it is **a** solution. I'm not sure how to show that it is the **only** solution for which $0 < A + B < 120^\circ$, other than to consider a function such as $f(x,y)=\sin^2x+\sin^2y-\sin(x+y)$ and find the extrema $\to$ this may be overkill for the problem.

Comment: You right, only I'm beginning to doubt this problem is correct. The condition (3) looks too weak to give only one solution ... but I might be wrong.

Comment: WolframAlpha seems to indicate that this might be the only solution for $C>A,B$, e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%5E2%28x%29+%2B+sin%5E2%28y%29+-+sin%28x%2By%29 . (I think the red zones are where the function is negative). Despite its apparent simplicity (and symmetry), eqn (3) has a lot of hidden venom!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%5E2%28x%29+%2B+sin%5E2%28y%29+-+sin%28x%2By%29%3D0%2Cx%3E%3D0%2Cy%3E%3D0%2Cx%2By%3C%3Dpi#

Comment: $a^2+b^2=c^2/ \sin C$ implies a<c>b (the sides)  so A<C>B (the angles) (re comment by Marconius)

Comment: Surely if $c$ is the longest side, then $C$ is the largest angle. $a^2+b^2=c^2/ \sin C$ just implies that $c^2\le(a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: @Marconius,how can we prove that $\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B=\sin(A+B)$ gives $A+B=\frac{\pi}{2}?$

Comment: $A+B=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is *a* solution, because then $\sin^2A+\sin^2B=\sin^2A+\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-A)=\sin^2A+\cos^2A=1$ and $\sin(A+B)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$. To prove that it is the *only* class of solutions for $A,B\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ is much more difficult. You can't use a trig identity because there **are** other solutions when $A,B$ are not restricted to $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Maybe QM-AM could work, but things could get really messy.